# C++ const-ness, Boost unordered map, operator[]

Tags: c++, boost, constants

I hope this question is answerable without seeing code, since I'm very unclear where the problem lies.  I'm using `operator[]` on a Boost unordered map to find a key and return the vector it's mapped to.  This is on the RHS of an assignment statement, but the error I'm getting seems to imply that `operator[]` doesn't guarantee constness.  I've just started trying to learn `const`-correctness.  Could someone decode this error and guide me to what the problem is?  Or ask for further details?

Compiler is **Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)**

```
Block.cpp:89:39: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const Record_map' (aka 'const unordered_map<Typecode, FV_pair_vec>')
    FV_pair_vec const fv_vec = records[rec_type];
                               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/unordered/unordered_map.hpp:420:22: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Record_map'
      (aka 'const unordered_map<Typecode, FV_pair_vec>'), but method is not marked const
        mapped_type& operator[](const key_type&);
                     ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the operator in question is not `const`, that is to say, it cannot be called on `const` objects, or via `const` references. An alternative that does provide a `const` version is `at(key_type const&)`, which will raise an exception if an element with that key element is not in the map. So you can use

```
mapped_type x = theMap.at(theKey);
```

instead of

```
mapped_type x = theMap[theKey];
```

Otherwise, use the `unordered_map::find(key_type const&)` method.